# Can I have a desktop icon for creating new documents from a template?

Tags: .desktop, templates

Is it possible to have an icon on the desktop so that when you double-click it it will create a new document from a certain template (`New Invoice.ots` located at `~/Templates`)? It would be a bit more visual than the right-click New Document -> New Invoice.

Comment: You could enhance your question BT specifying an invoice directory name. When you right click it finds the last invoice filename and adds 1 to it. For example: Inv1001, Inv1002, etc. But of course only if you want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new launcher in desktop which will help achieving your goal. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Create a `.desktop` file (say `template-generator.desktop`) in `~/Desktop`.
2. Open the `.desktop` file with a text-editor.
3. Add the following lines and save the file.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Launcher to create a file from a template
   Terminal=false
   Name=Create Invoice from Template
   Exec=/home/MyUsername/Templates/new_invoice.sh
   Type=Application
   Icon=/full/path/to/your/preferred/icon-file
   ```

   (Put your username in place of `MyUsername`.)
4. Create the script `new_invoice.sh` in the Templates folder:

   ```
   template="$HOME/Templates/New Invoice.ots"
   filename="$HOME/Documents/Invoice from $(date).ods"
   cp "$template" "$filename"
   xdg-open "$filename"
   ```
5. Right click on the file, open *Properties* > *Permissions*, and select "*allow executing file as program*". Do the same for the `.desktop` file.
6. Double click on the file. A warning window may appear asking you to "*Trust and Launch*". Do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to know first is where templates are stored and recognize their extensions. Eg LibreOffice  has its main template extension as **.ott** and stores its built-in document templates in */usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/common/*, and from there it's split under various folders according to the type of template - */usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/common/personal/CV.ott* as one example. So any personal templates created by yourself could be stored there, or kept under your Home folder, eg *Home/Templates* already exists. But I prefer to keep all templates under one roof rather than scattering them around.

So if you want to put a template onto your desktop, simply copy it (in our example *CV.ott*) and paste it to Home/Desktop. You can rename it, eg, MyCV. Just remember, once it's opened to save as a text document, eg **.odt** Job done.